# What's $\sqrt{1+\sin 2 \theta}+\sqrt{1-\sin 2\theta}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

What's $\sqrt{1+\sin 2 \theta}+\sqrt{1-\sin 2\theta}$ if $\theta \in \left(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4} \right)$.

Working so far:

Took the given equation as x
Squared on both sides.
got $x^2=2+(2)^{1/2}\cdot \cos(2\theta)$.
I'm stuck thereafter on how to convert that into one of the answers given below.

Comment: Please do not post your homework questions here without showing us what you have attempted.

Comment: Im sorry about that, Will learn but this was my first question here.

Comment: Jay: Oops, You're the one who is expected to show your workings up to when you got stuck.  So "Please show your working" first. And no, start learning now, given David's correct comment, by editing your post to include (and show) what you've tried, so we may better know how to help you here.

Comment: I cant post pics yet so ill try type it here in comments. Feel free to point out. The asnwers are in terms of trignometric terms

Comment: For $\theta=\pi/2$, the expression is $\sqrt{1-0}+\sqrt{1+0}=2$.

Comment: @JayPatil You can type equations using MathJax (like I did). You can find some tips at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I meant to ask only for 9th one

Comment: @amWhy Edited the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $1=\sin^2A+\cos^2A $ and $\sin2A=2\sin A \cos A$ to get $$\sqrt{\sin^2A+\cos^2A-2\sin A\cos A} + \sqrt{\sin^2A+\cos^2A+2\sin A\cos A}$$
$$=\sqrt{{(\sin A+\cos A)}^2}+\sqrt{{(\sin A-\cos A)^2}}$$
$$=\sin A+\cos A+\sin A-\cos A=2\sin A$$

Comment: Thank You. Thats a new perspective of substitution for me.